# USB Audio Gadget Driver: How to rename/define displayed UAC1 device name at host device

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, driver, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I created an USB audio gadget using USB Audio Class 1 (UAC1) to send/receive audio over USB from a Linux device (Raspberry Pi) to/from a Windows host. The gadget is already working and Windows detects the Raspberry Pi as an audio in and output.

The problem I have is, that the audio output device is called "AC Interface" and the input audio device is called "capture input terminal (AC Interface) in Windows". However, I would like to define an own name, that will be display at the host. Can somebody help me how to do this?

I tried to change the name using `uac1_legacy` (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/configfs-usb-gadget-uac1_legacy), but I couldn't manged to add this to the script.

Or do I have to configure the USB audio gadget using gadget schemes?

```sh
# Load libcomposite
modprobe libcomposite

# Create USB Gadget 
mkdir -p /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1

# Device Descriptors
echo 0x1d6b > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/idVendor # Linux Foundation
echo 0x0104 > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/idProduct # Multifunction Composite Gadget
echo 0x0100 > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/bcdDevice # v1.0.0
echo 0x0200 > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/bcdUSB # USB 2.0
echo 0xef > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/bDeviceClass # USB 2.0
echo 0x02 > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/bDeviceSubClass # USB 2.0
echo 0x01 > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/bDeviceProtocol # USB 2.0
mkdir -p /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/strings/0x409
echo "000001" > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "xy" > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "xy" > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/strings/0x409/product

# Configure UAC1 (audio) 
mkdir -p /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/uac1.usb0
echo 0x1 > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/uac1.usb0/c_chmask
echo 48000 > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/uac1.usb0/c_srate
echo 0xf > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/uac1.usb0/p_chmask
echo 48000 > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/uac1.usb0/p_srate
mkdir -p /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/c.1
echo 250 > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/c.1/MaxPower
ln -s /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/uac1.usb0 /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/c.1/
udevadm settle -t 5 || :

# End
ls /sys/class/udc/ > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/sonoDSP_audio/UDC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `f_uac1.c`. For me it seems you can not change the gstrings on the fly for the predefined funcation f_uac.

```c
static struct usb_string strings_uac1[] = {
    [STR_AC_IF].s = "AC Interface",
    ...,
    [STR_IO_IN_IT].s = "Capture Input terminal",
    ...,
    { }
};
```

What you can do is, creating a simple functionfs user space program with your custom configurations. See the following for further details on ffs.

How to load ffs?
See: https://github.com/linkjumper/configfs/blob/master/setup_usb_gadget.sh

Documentation on how to write a userspace functionfs:
See: `linux/tools/usb/ffs-test.c`. (Spoiler, those testfile did not work for all endpoints to me. But it is a good source as an example.)

It is a little work, but worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! As far as I understand, I call your program (GitHub) with the compiled ffs file as argument.

I took a look at the GitHub code and I have a few questions. 
1. Are the sourcesink and loopback cases important for my case or can I delte them?
2. I have problems to start my USB Device Controller (UDC) with the GitHub code. But I always get the error message, "no such device". -> I checked " sys/class/udc": no device is listed. In my solution I used "/sys/class/udc/ > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC" to start the UDC.

Comment: 1. Just for debugging purposes; 2. Yes, the platform can differ. Please update the local variables in the script for your needs. I updated the [Readme.md](https://github.com/linkjumper/configfs/blob/master/README.md) by the way.